# Best way to make webpack run a script in browser?

Tags: javascript, webpack

I want Webpack to execute a script (that is provided by my npm package) in the browser, without needing to include that script in my app. Currently, I am using webpack.config.dev.js to force it, like this:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: [
    paths.appIndexJs,
    "./node_modules/my-dev-package/client.js"
  ]
}
```

client.js contains an IIFE that modifies the DOM. I want to avoid having to add conditional logic to my application to check for the environment, when I really just need something appended to the DOM in development. Is there a more standard way to get this same effect, without having to import client.js inside my app and conditionally run it there?

I am new to webpack, so if there is a standard way to do this or a commonly used plugin, that's what I'm looking for.